# Eta Squared Confusion

Tags: effect-size, generalized-eta-squared

I'm working on some research and would like to ask for some help regarding the use of Eta-Squared. Our school's review board recommended the use of the statistic for my study which is looking to correlate nurse job satisfaction, occupational stress, and reason for seeking work abroad. My confusion stems from how the review board redesigned my tool. For example, for occupational stress, it looks like this:

[image]

Am I correct to assume that I am computing this on a **per item basis** and not on a **per respondent basis**? Because it seems the review board wants me to see the effect size for each item rather than a comparison between respondent A's stress levels and reason for leaving 'levels', for example.

Also, would it be prudent to include a correlation statistic (maybe Pearson R)? Because it seems I already assume that these items are already significantly correlated with leaving one's job, which doesn't seem right from a statistical point of view (assuming I mean).

Oh, also I'll be using SPSS v23.

Any advice would be most appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What are your data like? I don't understand the table you present.  My guess is that you should be doing something else, but I really can't tell what.

Comment: Hi @gung! I have nominal data from the demographic variables and the rest would be ordinal data from scores from Likert scales like in the picture. The picture is part of my questionnaire.

Comment: This still doesn't make any sense to me.  What are the `4 3 2 1` columns? What are the subsequent columns? Can you post your data, or a small sample of them?

Comment: @gung In order from left to right in the picture 4 - always, 3 - sometimes, 2 - rarely, 1 - never; (Is this a reason for leaving?) 1 - strong disagree, 2 - disagree, 3 - neutral, 4 - agree, 5 - strongly agree

Comment: "4 - always, 3 - sometimes, 2 - rarely, 1 - never" what?

Comment: Let me use the picture as an example. Like, I "always" frequent headaches (if 4 is answered). Or, I "rarely" experience backaches (if 2 is answered). The tool is there to assess the respondents' occupational stress levels.